# How to solve incorrect dependencys using maven and openapi

Tags: spring-boot, maven, openapi

in our springboot project we are using openapi to generate the representation of our data. But if i try to build the project it looks the generated classes/Interfaces are missing all dependencys. I get a lot of errors saying something like `java: package io.swagger.annotations does not exist` or `java: package springfox.documentation.annotations does not exist`.

However the dependencys should be there. The project has 2 pom.xml files. One in the main directory of the project and one in the src directory of the generated data. The pom in the src directory contains

```
 <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--SpringFox dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- Bean Validation API support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Here all the needed dependencys like `swagger` are listed. Thats why I do not understand how there are all these errors saying the packages can not be found. I have no idea why this happens so i would be really grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: What is springfox-version? Maybe try 2.9.2. This version successfully working on my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching to version 2.92 on both dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

With the versions changed if you use SpringToolSuite4, forcing the Update Maven Project should work:
Project > Update Maven Project > Force Update of Snapshots/Releases